# Why do I need to run GPIO as root even with GPIO Ver 0.6.2?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

Trying to use GPIO in Python, but it only works if I change to root.  Why?  The description for GPIO Ver 0.6.2 indicates that root is no longer needed?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/os-release` and `uname -a`?

Comment: look here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root, I think you need to change the access rights to /dev/mem

Comment: @lexu To use RPi.GPIO without being root /dev/gpiomem needs to exist with the correct permissions and the user (default pi) needs to be a member of group gpio.

Comment: This solves the immediate problem but it must be redone after a reboot, how can it be done to survive a reboot?