# Set permissions and group for /dev/gpiomem permanently

Tags: gpio, permissions, user

I need to allow my user access to the GPIO pins and found following solution.
[Access GPIO pins without root. No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root)

This works perfectly. All I need to do is execute following commands to set the group and permissions for /dev/gpiomem.

```
sudo chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem
sudo chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem
```

After this /dev/gpiomem has following permissions.

```
$ ls -l /dev/gpiomem
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 243, 0 Dec 24 13:55 /dev/gpiomem
```

The problem is, that the permissions are reset to following permissions after reboot.

```
$ ls -l /dev/gpiomem
crw------- 1 root root 243, 0 Dec 24 13:55 /dev/gpiomem
```

How can I make my changes on /dev/gpiomem permission permanently?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think that `udev` should do the trick... as goldilock's outlines in the linked answer.