# What sets ownership and privileges on /dev/gpiomem?

Tags: gpio

[This post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root) has a nice solution for using GPIO (and I2C) without root-privileges. This is useful if you're running an (web) app in a virtual environment as some ve-user, so as to shield off your whole Pi from that ve-user. But let's not digress.

The solution is basically that your ve-user must be member of gpio, and that root:gpio (not root:root) owns `/dev/gpio`.

```
pi@RPi2a ~ $ ls -l /dev/gpiomem  
crw------- 1 root root 245, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/gpiomem   # BEFORE  
pi@RPi2a ~ $ sudo chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem && sudo chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem  
pi@RPi2a ~ $ ls -l /dev/gpiomem  
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 245, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/gpiomem   # AFTER
```

The thing is: after a reboot, it's all back to the BEFORE situation. So how do you make it stick? Googling some, I found it's [ruled](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=153654) by `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules`.
I guess (correctly?) root executes this at boot time. In it, there is:

```
PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/gpio; chown -R root:gpio /sys/devices/virtual/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/virtual/gpio'"  
SUBSYSTEM=="input", GROUP="input", MODE="0660"  
SUBSYSTEM=="i2c-dev", GROUP="i2c", MODE="0660"  
SUBSYSTEM=="spidev", GROUP="spi", MODE="0660"
```

So I inserted this into the first line, just before the closing `'"`:

```
; chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem && chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem
```

But that didn't work, nor did this variation: `chown root:gpio /dev/gpiomem && chmod 660 /dev/gpiomem`). So I've added that line to root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) like this:

```
@reboot chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem && chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem
```

This works, but it looks to me like fighting the symptom rather than the cause. So I tried to find what resets the ownership on `/dev/gpiomem`:

```
sudo grep -rnw /etc/ -e "/dev/gpio"
```

to no avail. Grepping the entire disk (`/` instead of `/etc/udev`) breaks with `grep: memory exhausted`. It's a 256 MB Pi. I'm using, and want to stick to, Adafruit's Wheezy.

So the question is: what, where, how & why manipulates /dev/gpiomem?

Comment: Why do you want to stick to Adafruit's distribution?  I didn't realise it still existed.

Comment: @joan I think the TFT driver that was added to the mainline kernel doesn't cover some of their smaller displays.

Comment: @joan I started out with Adafruit's Wheezy because at the time, it had a bunch of stuff pre-installed (i2c, smbus, and more) that 'normal' Wheezy had not. Later on, I had to work around out-of-memory errors compiling `lxml`, which I need for my project. I'm hesitating to move to Jessie, because I don't want to go through all those motions again. That's the reason.

Comment: If you have a spare SD card I'd try a mainstream distribution.  Adafruit's is now a dead end.

Comment: @joan It's just Wheezy and some. Still updates and upgrades. I do see advantages in Jessie, but there are some 30 non-standard libraries, packages and countless evenings of configuration and tweaking in my current set-up. That I don't want to do all over again. With a new Pi, I certainly will, tho'.

Comment: My bad, I thought you meant Occidentalis.

Comment: @Joan LOL, my bad too, sort of. It's the Wheezy you used to get with [Adafruit's Pi finder](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Pi-Finder#adafruit-raspberry-pi-finder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what, where, how & why manipulates /dev/gpiomem?

Anything that has the correct permissions, so *without* the udev adjustment, any privileged process.

The adjustment is made by `udevd`, an [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) service daemon.

> So I tried two add this to the first line

Beware those `.rules` files are not shell scripts.  However, you can change this:

```
PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R root:gpio ....`
```

To the path to a shell script:

```
PROGRAM="/etc/udev/local_scripts/do_what_I_want.sh"
```

Which will make things a little tidier.  I just made that path up (there is no `/etc/udev/local_scripts` directory); you can put it anywhere, but you must include an appropriate shebang and set `$PATH` in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

**However**, the reason this will not work:

```
chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem && chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem
```

Is because when the `PROGRAM=` entry is run, the device node does not exist yet ([see here](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run), and also scroll up to see the previous section).  But, as per that, what's indicated by `RUN` is executed *after* the device node is created (also note *"PROGRAM is used for running programs which produce device names (and they shouldn't do anything other than that)"*).  So you could instead try:

```
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem && chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem'"
```

Or, as just explained, put whatever you want to do in a script and execute it via the same parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected and (hopefully) clarified the question. Do I understand right that (1) the `PROGRAM=..` clause sets the device node up, and (2) it gets `root:root` because that's simply what the setting up does?

Comment: The whole thing doesn't actually need to exist; if not, the kernel will create the node anyway with whatever default settings it uses (almost certainly, root access only).  The point of udev is to inject changes, etc., into the process.  So you can do stuff before the node is created via `PROGRAM`, including control the name of the node (as explained in that link), and after via `RUN`.