# RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem

Tags: pi-3, led, setup, script, python-3

I'm using the PXfmini with the raspberrypi3 for a project and I need to use mavros and python code.
My operative system is Frambuesa.
I created the catkin workspace and I tested the c++ file takeoff_land_ and it works very well.

Now I need to test the python code, because I have to work with it, I’m using this example and I followed all the instructions to compile the **statusleds.py** :

https://github.com/erlerobot/ros_erle_statusled

But this is the error that the screen showed me:

[image: this]

How can I fix this?

I already tried this commands:
[Access GPIO pins without root. No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root)

thank you :)

Comment: To confirm, have you tried running it as root as suggested (`sudo rosrun ...`)? What happens if you do that?

Comment: sudo rosrun ros_erle_statusled statusleds.py 
[sudo] password for erle: 
sudo: rosrun: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspbian supports the `/dev/gpiomem` device which allows access to the GPIO without being the root user.

If `/dev/gpiomem` does not exist on your system you will need to run the Python script as the root user (with all the risks that entails).

Comment: But when I write:  sudo python statusleds.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "statusleds.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rospy
ImportError: No module named rospy

Comment: That is a path problem.  You need to install rospy in a standard location so that it is in the path of the root user.