# WS281x library cannot access /dev/mem without root

Tags: gpio, permissions, root, ws2812

I get this error from the [rpi_ws281x library](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x) when trying to run as user pi (this is a java wrapper around the library):

```
16:43:59.060 [main] INFO  com.github.mbelling.ws281x.Ws281xLedStrip - LEDs count: 1, GPIO pin: 18, freq hZ: 800000, DMA: 10, brightness: 255, pwm channel: 0, invert: false, strip type: WS2811_STRIP_GRB, clear on exit: true
16:43:59.142 [main] INFO  com.github.mbelling.ws281x.Ws281xLedStrip - Native library loaded
Can't open /dev/mem: Permission denied
!! Failed to initialize WS2811:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup lights driver, result code: WS2811_ERROR_MMAP
    at com.github.mbelling.ws281x.Ws281xLedStrip.init(Ws281xLedStrip.java:234)
    at com.github.mbelling.ws281x.Ws281xLedStrip.<init>(Ws281xLedStrip.java:98)
```

I already followed all possible steps from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root), like setting the permissions of `/dev/mem` and adding user to group `gpio`, reboot etc. No success. The problem persists. I cannot run my application as super user, as it would screw up a lot of file access and caches I am writing. I really need to be able to run the WS2811 library as a normal user.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The library needs root permissions to run.

Comment: I am asking for a way to give `pi` the required permissions, so I can run the process as `pi` and not super-user

Comment: That becomes a standard permissions problem, i.e. not Pi specific.

Comment: That's a Pi specific problem because it is about using a common library for WS2811 LEDs via the GPIO, and requiring the PWM of GPIO 18, which is related to the permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems no way around it. A solution with added latency is to run a separate process on root to control the GPIO, and communicate to it from a user process, e.g. using OSC commands.