# Can't change ownership of '/dev/gpiomem' in a docker container in RPi

Tags: pi-4, docker

I'm trying to run a simple docker container with a python base image to control the LEDs on my RPi4.

The Dockerfile compiles fine and I'm running it as follows: `docker run --rm -ti --privileged --device /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem -d led_blinker bash`

Once inside the docker container I run a ls -l /dev/gpiomem and I get

```
root@ca1506d00cc5:/# ls -l /dev/gpiomem
crw-rw---- 1 nobody nogroup 246, 0 Dec 30 21:47 /dev/gpiomem
```

I try to do

```
root@ca1506d00cc5:/# chown root.root /dev/gpiomem
chown: changing ownership of 'dev/gpiomem': Operation not permitted
```

But when I run a `whoami` I get I'm the root user. What is that I'm missing?

PS. I have also added the flag `--user root` and got the same results.

Comment: Did you test that it really doesn't work the way it is?

Comment: I did. I'm trying to use `gpiozero` library and it throws an error when trying to access the device that I need root access. Looking at this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root) seems I need to set the correct permisions, which I can't do for some reason

Comment: That post is for running without docker (and it is outdated as well, as this has been fixed meanwhile). I have never used docker on the Pi, but (here)[https://github.com/dotnet/iot/tree/main/samples/led-blink] is another example that shows that it should normally be working just fine.

Comment: I ended up doing a fresh install on the pi, and the post you linked worked, and was able to get mine to work as well. I think experimenting with Docker on the pi might have messed up some config